# Node, express, passport - updating session after updating record

Tags: node.js, session, session-variables, updates, passport.js

I'm rather new to node, I have started writing a small app and am working on my user auth and profile. I'm using express, passport and ejs. I've got passport working and have my user redirecting to a profile page that requires additional data before the user begin's to use the application. My question is:

What's the proper way to update the user's session (created at passport.authentication) when a user updates their profile data? I would like to update the user session in order to hit it rather than the data base for basic user data.

Comment: Finally answered...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493243/update-logged-in-user-details-in-session/24498660#24498660

Answer (score 0):

If your using express you have middleware that looks like:

```
function (res, req, next){}
```

When you get session data you can add it to the req object.

```
function (res, req, next){
    // get the session here...
    req.session = session;

}
```

Then any other middleware will have access to the req.session object which will contain the user's session.