# Update logged in user details in session

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using PassportJS with ExpressJS.

I need to update the logged in user details. While I do update this in the DB, how do I update it in the session too so that request.user contains the updated user details?

That is, after updating the database, how do I update the session info on the user as well?

I tried directly assigning the updated details to `request.user` but it did not work.
I then tried `request.session.passport.user` - this worked but there is a delay of around 5 to 10 seconds before it gets updated in request.user too.

Is there a function that I need to call that updates the user information stored in the session? Or is there some other object that I can update where the change does not have a delay

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I've been hunting down an answer for this too. Never mentioned in any docs or tutorials!

What seems to work is, after saving your newly updated user, do `req.login(user)`...

```
// "user" is the user with newly updated info
user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    // What's happening in passport's session? Check a specific field...
    console.log("Before relogin: "+req.session.passport.user.changedField)
    
    req.login(user, function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        
        console.log("After relogin: "+req.session.passport.user.changedField)
        res.send(200)
    })
})
```

The clue was here... https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/208

---

#### EDIT 2023

Apparently, since `passport@0.6.0`, `req.login()` now generates a new session ID, which means this approach may no longer work. Stick to the previous version (0.5.3) for now? Here's a tiny bit [more detail](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/208#issuecomment-1658188560) .

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. This seems to be the correct way to update the session data since `login` calls the passport serializer function that updates the user data stored in the session. However, for some reason, I experienced delays in updating the session so the `res.send(200)` equivalent code in my application was placed inside a `setTimeout` function of 2 seconds - that helped.

Comment: Very weird. So if you do two console logs like in my example, the second one still shows the old data? You'd think by the time the req.login callback happens, every async change would have been performed. Well, if a 2 sec wait fixes it every time, you're good.

Answer (score 1):

```
User.findById(req.user._id,function(err,doc){
        req.logIn(doc,function(err1){

                if(err1){ console.log("Error : "+err1) }
                              else{
                                    res.render("abc.ejs",{user:req.user});
                                    console.log('Item Removed Successfully!!!');
                              }

                        });
                  });
```

Here we are re-login the user

User => Mongoose Model

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem today and decided to share my findings, since i couldn't find similar answer.

The problem was that (copied from passport documentation) i was getting the user data directly from the token, that the user sent in the request. Which was of course outdated.

```
passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey   : CONFIG.JWT_SECRET
  },
  function (jwtPayload, cb) {
    return cb(null, jwtPayload);
  }
));
```

while i should get the fresh user object from the database instead:

```
return User.findById(jwtPayload.id)
  .then(user => {
    return cb(null, user);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    return cb(err);
  });
```