# Manually Log In User - Passport.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

My goal is to have one post route with two options - either the user already has an account or doesn't. If the user does not have an account it creates an account - this is working. However if the user does have an account I'm needing to update their current info and then log them in.

**Everything is working however I have not been able how to log in the user if they already have an account. Is this possible?**

```
 router.post("/career-test", function(req, res){

    User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (err) {
    return done(err);
    }

    if (!existingUser) {


    var newUser = new User({username: req.body.username});
    console.log('newUser' + newUser)
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){

        user.career1.name =  req.body.career1Name;
        user.career2.name =  req.body.career2Name;
        user.career3.name =  req.body.career3Name;
        user.career4.name =  req.body.career4Name;
        user.career5.name =  req.body.career5Name;
        user.save()

    if(err){
    req.flash("error", err.message);
    res.redirect('back')
    return res.render("register");

    }
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
    res.redirect("/results"); 
    });
    });

    } else {
```

**THIS IS IF THE USER ALREADY EXISTS / IS FOUND**

```
      existingUser.career1.name =  req.body.career1Name;
      existingUser.career2.name =  req.body.career2Name;
      existingUser.career3.name =  req.body.career3Name;
      existingUser.career4.name =  req.body.career4Name;
      existingUser.career5.name =  req.body.career5Name;
      existingUser.save()
```

**NOW I NEED TO LOGIN EXISTING USER... IS THIS POSSIBLE?**

```
    res.redirect("/results"); 
    });
    }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its very easy. Found the answer here: [Update logged in user details in session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493243/update-logged-in-user-details-in-session)

After saving the existingUser data simply do this:

```
req.login(existingUser, function(err) {
  if (err) return next(err)
});
```